# How do I use a wrapper function that generates a variable from a function, and pass decorate another function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that I would like to use a decorator when running sp500_rsi:

```
def generate_sp500(start_date):
    "block of code to generate pandas dataframe"
    return sp500
```

In the following function is where I would like to replace the block of code that generates the variable sp500 below:

```
def sp500_rsi(start_date, rsi):
    sp500 = generate_sp500() "would like to replace this with a decorator"
    sp500['rsi'] = "some methods that populates the new column with values"
```

What I would like to do is:

```
@sp500_decorator
def sp500_rsi(rsi):
    return sp500
```

Ideally, `sp500_rsi` could use the variable `sp500` that `generate_sp500()` creates.

I tried to creating the decorator, however I can't get the function I want to decorate to recognise the `sp500` variable.

I'm seeing other threads with someone with a similar issue but not quite the same `using *args`. Not sure if that is the way to go in my decorator function and how.

Answer (score 0):

This is about function scoping, variables that are not in the agreed scope cannot be called. You can try to set the variable "sp500" to a global variable。

```
global sp500
```